# Create an array of (non unique) random numbers in a certain range

Tags: php, arrays

I'm attempting to create four arrays of random numbers, and merge those arrays into one.  The print results are just there to help me verify the data in the arrays.

The part I can't seem to get working are the parts commented "generate 116 commons and generate 46 uncommons".  The arrays don't seem to contain any data.

```
<?php

$common = array();
$uncommon = array();

//generate 116 random numbers in the range of 35-74 in an array called $common
for($i = 0; $i < 116; i++){
    $common[] = mt_rand(35, 74);
}

//generate 46 random numbers in the range 75-106 in an array called $uncommon
for($i = 0; $i < 46; i++){
    $uncommon[] = mt_rand(75, 106);
}

//generate 16 random numbers in the range 107-134 in an array called $rare.  No duplicates are allowed.
$rare = range(107, 134);
shuffle($rare );
$rare = array_slice($rare ,0, 16);

//generate 2 random numbers in an array called $superrare. No duplicates are allowed.
$superrare = range(135, 142);
shuffle($superrare );
$superrare = array_slice($superrare ,0, 2);

//merge the arrays and shuffle the feed
$feed = array_merge($common, $uncommon, $rare, $superrare);
//shuffle($feed);

//print results
echo "<br> <br> common: ";
print_r($common);
echo "<br> <br> uncommon: ";
print_r($uncommon);
echo "<br> <br> rare: ";
print_r($rare);
echo "<br> <br> super rare: ";
print_r($superrare);
echo "<br> <br> feed: ";
print_r($feed);

?>
```

Comment: How would you get 46 uncommon between range 75 to 106, I don't see enough for 46

Comment: @SameerJain The array just isn't going to be having unique numbers, that's it.

Comment: What you have is syntax errors, thus you don't see anything. `i++` in the loop conditions are missing a dollar sign, should be `$i++` in both loops. https://3v4l.org/NDWTW

Comment: Thank you Charlotte, that was it. /facepalm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you haven't the $ mark in the for line **$**i++

```
//generate 116 random numbers in the range of 35-74 in an array called $common
for($i = 0; $i < 116; $i++){
    $common[] = mt_rand(35, 74);
}

//generate 46 random numbers in the range 75-106 in an array called $uncommon
for($i = 0; $i < 46; $i++){
    $uncommon[] = mt_rand(75, 106);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it.  I looked at that code for an hour and couldn't figure out what was missing.  Won't do that again.